# How to un-mirror a display with xrandr

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I have a laptop with two monitors configured to the right of it.  Often after the laptop has hibernated overnight and I open it up my HDMI monitor ends up mirroring my laptop screen or my VGA for some reason.

I know that mirroring can be done by doing:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --same-as VGA-1
```

But I would like to do the exact opposite.  How do I un-mirror my HDMI monitor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --left-of VGA-1
```

or

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --right-of VGA-1
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I case you have run a `xrandr` `reflect` command like `xrandr --output [device] --reflect xy`, this can be reverted by

```bash
xrandr --output [device] --reflect normal
```